# How to pass Url.Action in <td> in Ajax Success function

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
 data: { "courseid": courseid, "date": coursedate, "place": courseplace , "status" : status },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#count").html(data.length);
                $("#count").html("<span>" + data.length + "</span>" + "<span> " + status + "</span>" + " Registration(s) Found For " + "<span>" + coursename + "</span>" + " In " + "<span>" + coursedate + "</span>" + " At " + "<span>" + courseplace + "</span>");
                allcourseresult.html('');
                $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                    //allcourseresult.append($('<p></p>').html(option.fname + option.coname + option.coplace + option.coloc + option.codate));
                    allcourseresult.append($('<tr></tr>').html("<td>" + option.coname + "</td>" + "<td>" + option.fname + "</td>" + "<td>" + option.codate + "</td>" + "<td>" + option.coplace + "</td>" + "<td>" + option.conf + "</td>"  + "<td>" + "@Url.Action('Edit', 'Customer', new { id =" + option.id + "})" ));
                });

                statesProgress.hide();
            },
```

I want to pass the Url.Action in the td tag , so that it is clickable , but this code doesnt work right ...
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: First you have to make sure this part of javascript happens in a .cshtml view, otherwise nothing will compile the `@Url.Action`. Second, you cannot use single quote (') for the parameters of `@Url.Action`, keep in mind that it is C# code, and single quote in C# code is for `char` not `string`. Use double quote for the controller and action name. Third, you are trying to add a javascript(client side) variable to your Html helper(server side), which cannot be done by this way.

Comment: how do i achieve this then...

Comment: In this specific case, simply make everything in javascript can make your life easier IMO. So replace the @Url.Action with a regular html `<a href='Build your url through javascript'></a>`. However I would suggest to read a bit more about basic asp.net mvc and html/javascript before you proceed.

Comment: did it with <a> tag , thanx :)